# Passing Struct * by reference C

Tags: c

+I'm trying to pass from the main an array of CustomStruct by reference, but im doing something wrong:

I think i'm asking correctly for memory, but it doesn't seem so, because when i try to force some values, i get core  dumped and i absolutely don't know why.

```
void readFile(OwnStruct **restaurant){

    FILE *f;                                                                                                                                                                                            
    int numTaules = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                  
    f = fopen("hello.txt", "r");                                                                                                                                                                      
    if(f == NULL){                                                                                                                                                                                      
        printf("Error at opening!\n");                                                                                                                                                          
        exit(0);                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    fscanf(f,"%d",&numTaules);                                                                                                                                                                          

    //Asking for memory                                                                                                                                                                                            
    *restaurant = (OwnStruct*)malloc(sizeof(OwnStruct) * numTaules);                                                                                                                                            

    //From here, at some point: Core Dumped                                                                                                                                                                                        
    restaurant[0]->ocupades = 1;                                                                                                                                                                        
    restaurant[0]->disponibles = 2;                                                                                                                                                                     
    restaurant[1]->ocupades = 3;                                                                                                                                                                        
    restaurant[1]->disponibles = 4;                                                                                                                                                                      
    printf("%d\n",restaurant[0]->ocupades);                                                                                                                                                             
    printf("%d\n",restaurant[0]->disponibles);                                                                                                                                                          
    printf("%d\n",restaurant[1]->ocupades);
    printf("%d\n",restaurant[1]->disponibles); 

}

int main(){

   typedef struct(){
       int ocupades;
       int disponibles;
   }

    OwnStruct *restaurant;

    readFile(&restaurant);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should verify that `numTaules` is at least 2 before proceeding.

Comment: The `typedef` is in the wrong place. The function is passed the wrong number of arguments. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried. "Core dumped" means your uncompilable code is not your actual code.

Comment: `restaurant[0]->ocupades = 1;` --> `(*restaurant)[0].ocupades = 1;` ditto.

Comment: C does not support references. It is strictly pass by value.

Answer (score 4):

You are referencing the array wrong:

So far so good:

```
*restaurant = (OwnStruct*)malloc(sizeof(OwnStruct) * numTaules);
```

This is wrong:

```
restaurant[0]->ocupades = 1;
```

It should be:

```
(*restaurant)[0].ocupades = 1;
```

You must dereference the pointer to your pointer. That expression then points to the first element of the allocated array.  The parentheses are needed, because postfix operators like `EXPR[0]` take precedence over unary operators like `*EXPR`, so `*EXPR[0]` is treated as `*(EXPR[0])`.

**Suggestion:**  Work with a local pointer which is just `Ownstruct *ptr`.  Then, just before returning from the function, store that pointer:

```
*restaurant = ptr;
```

Then you can just have `ptr[0]->field = value` type code in your function.

Comment: Should that be `(*restaurant)[0].ocupades`?

Comment: Yep! it's (*restaurant)[0].ocupades

Thanks a lot!!

PD: I already did it whit local pointer, but i wanted to know why it wasn't working as commented. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @kaylum Yes, sorry; of course, if we have `->`, `[]` **and** `*`, then we're *triple* dereferencing!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your function

```
void readFile(char fileName[], OwnStruct **restaurant)
```

expects two parameter, but you pass just one.

```
readFile(&restaurant);
```

Just write

```
readFile("myFile.txt", &restaurant);
```

or define your function as

```
void readFile(OwnStruct **restaurant)
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you give should not currently compile - readFile expects a filename and a pointer to a pointer of OwnStruct. Your main is just providing the pointer.

The struct should defined somewhere at the top (before its use in main and readFile)

readFile is also reading numTauls from a file but then assuming it is at least 2 when assigning values to the allocated memory.